# In PHP Add the duplicate values in array

Tags: php

I have n number of textbox to get the name of the products and their quantity. So i used PHP array to get the value and its working fine. I tried the logic like if the user give duplicate products, then duplicate products is removed but their quantity is added with the same products.

```
<form method="post" action ="insert.php">
<input type =text name ="products[]" value = "">
<input type =text name ="quantity[]" value = "">
<!-- ...........
n numbers of textbox to add the products and quantity
--------- -->

<input type ="submit" value="submit"> </form>
```

insert.php:

```
$products = $_POST['products'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
for($i=0;$i<count($products);$i++)
 {
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (`products`,`quantity`) VALUES ('$products[$i]','$quantity[$i]')";
mysql_query($query);
}
```

the array come like

```
$products[0] = "Apple"  $quantity[0] = "20"
$products[1] = "Orange"  $quantity[1] = "10"
$products[2] = "Apple"  $quantity[2] = "30"
```

Here products name apple is duplicate it occurs two times. So i remove the duplicate name apple and their quantity value should be added like 50(20+30)

Comment: so, if the product name is same then you want to add the quantity, right ?

Comment: @criesto - yes, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would normalize the tables and just insert product_id(primary key) ,quantity  and do the following (using binded vars):

```
INSERT INTO stock (product_id,quantity) VALUES ($1,$2 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + $2
```

If there already are `Apples` (id=2) in the table we update the quantity

If you **don't want to normalize** the tables and use what you have the same applies:

1. Make `product` column primary key
2. Use     `INSERT INTO stock (product,quantity) VALUES ($1,$2 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + $2`

OR(but I don't really like it):

```
$distinct = array();
foreach($products as $index=>$product) {
    if(!isset($distinct[$product])) {
        $distinct[$product] = $quantity[$index];
    } else {
        $distinct[$product] += $quantity[$index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this table product_id is not a primary key.

Comment: I just said what I would do, read from the bolded text down :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$products = $_POST['products'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$productQuantity = array();

foreach($products as $key => $product) {
    if (!array_key_exists($product, $productQuantity) {
        $productQuantity[ $product ] = 0;
    }
    $productQuantity[ $product ] += $quantity[ $key ];
}
```

Then you will end up with an array

```
$productQuantity['Apple'] => 50
$productQuantity['Orange'] => 10
```

So, to add it to the database, you could do:

```
foreach($productQuantity as $name => $qty) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (`products`,`quantity`) VALUES ('$name','$qty')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: its fine. If i have a another textbox name like `price[]`